# Map.compute function in java

Tags: java, hashmap, conditional-operator

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication32 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Name", "Aman");
        map.put("Address", "Kolkata");
        map.compute("Name", (key, val) -> (val == null) ? "Gaurav" : val = "Great");
        System.out.println(map.get("Name"));
    }
}
```

The above code shows an error. But when the value data type is chosen as `int`, the code works.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does the error say? Please take a look at [ask].

Comment: Well.. I have an idea what the error is (`val` being final?) but why don't you include the error and your idea of what causes it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to assign  `val`

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication32 {

public static void main(String args[])
{
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
 map.put("Name", "Aman"); 
 map.put("Address", "Kolkata"); 
 map.compute("Name", (key, val)  -> ( val==null) ? "Gaurav" : "Great"); 
 System.out.println(map.get("Name"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
map.compute("Name", (key, val)  -> ( val==null) ? "Gaurav" : val="Great");
```

with

```
map.compute("Name", (key, val) -> (val == null) ? "Gaurav" : "Great");
```

**Output:**

```
Great
```

**Explanation:**
The syntax of ternary operator is as follows:

```
variable = condition ? value-if-condition-is-true : value-if-condition-is-false
```

e.g. the following code assigns the value of `x` into `z`

```
int x = 10, y = 5, z;
z = x > y ? x : y;
System.out.println(z);
```

However, if at all you want to keep the left operand inside the statement, you can do it using `()` as follows:

```
map.compute("Name", (key, val) -> (val == null) ? "Gaurav" : (val = "Great"));
```

Similarly,

```
z = x > y ? x : (z = y);
```

Even though these two statements given above will be compiled successfully, I recommend you never do it like this as it will simply confuse anyone going through your code.